# WPF Image Transformation

Tags: c#, wpf, image, animation, transformation

I have simple graphic images which I would like to transform on triggered events. Transform means change the width or move it to another position.

For now I use the Image element of the toolbox and Animations via Storyboard, for instance DoubleAnimation or ThicknessAnimation.

However the following issues arise:

1. the images flickers when changing the width
2. the image quality varies, does WPF support vector graphics?

Regarding 1. my question is, if other animations should be used.

---

So I tried the Transformation, see the code :

```
    <Image Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,0,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="images/side_view.jpg" Width="1244">
        <Image.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform x:Name="Minimize"  ScaleX="1.0" ScaleY="1.0"/>
        </Image.RenderTransform>
    </Image>

    <Button Content="Next Train" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="528,233,0,0" Name="btnNext" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
    <Grid.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click" SourceName="btnNext">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard TargetName="Minimize" TargetProperty="ScaleX">
                    <DoubleAnimation To="0.65" Duration="0:0:2"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
```

Works the same as the Animation I applied to width and margin. However, it still flickers! Are there any reasonable explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're animating the Width of an image, you're making WPF re render the image, and create it from scatch each time. It goes through both the Layout process and the Rendering process, which makes it flicker and not work as best as it could be.

The best option here is to animate a ScaleTransform. ScaleTransform is done completely in hardware via DirectX and therefor will be extremlely fast, it won't flicker, and the image quality should stay pretty much the same the whole way. (unless ofcourse you are resizing it substantially in which case you'll lose percision.)

Comment: @eldad-katz: I tried the ScaleTransform, however the result is the same - any ideas?

Comment: It should work as suggested. In the code you put I don't see the ScaleTransform that's named Minimize.. but anyhow, it should work perfectly. are you sure that all you are doing is animating the ScaleTransform?

Comment: @elad-katz: You are right, I put in the wrong codes together. However they don't differ that much, I edited it. Maybe it's already doing fine, but it does not meet my imaginations. This is the complete code: http://pastebin.com/cYx5exFx

Comment: I copy-paste it to my machine and it works perfectly, very fast and all... either something else is screwing it on your computer, or else maybe you are using one hell of a large image. in any case, the code should work very fast for you.